# Getting rid of Microsoft Edge or disabling it

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

For some strange reason, all the icons on my desktop accessing websites became 'Microsoft Edge' when I switched from Chrome to Edge for one browsing session! I tried everything to get rid of it, but no luck! Also, when I want to make Mozilla Firefox my default browser, as soon as I click OK, an 'Edge' page comes up thus nullifying my preference! Apparently, Microsoft has a wired software app overriding one's choice? How can I disable it or get rid of it so I can get back my browser of choice?

Comment: It would be easier to just just the default browser back to your original selection.  Removing Edge WILL NOT solve your current problem by the way.

Comment: He's probably getting the "something wrong with your default browser" message when trying to switch defaults.

Comment: This is because Windows 10 has the most ridiculous way of changing your default browser. You can see how to do it [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-change-your-default-browser-windows-10).

Comment: @DrZoo To be fair the process hasn't really changed.  You also set the default browser the same way, how it looked has changed, but you intentially perform the same steps

Answer (score 0):

windows 10 requires you to choose your default browser in the settings area of windows - (you can no longer just 'set this browser as default' within the browser application

go to settings/ system / default apps - and you can choose what you use under "web browser" heading

Note - edge is also the default pdf reader in windows 10 too..

Comment: How about more specifics?  How does this differ from the duplicate questions answer?  Besides the fact is less detailed.